# How to review complex cherry-picks with gerrit

Tags: git, gerrit

I have two branches: `master` and `release`. Now I want to cherry-pick commits `A`, `B`, `C`, `D` from the `release` branch back to `master`. These commits are not consecutive, so I cannot use the `^` syntax. I did:

- Cherry pick these commits individually by `git cherry-pick A`, `git cherry-pick B`, etc.
- These cherry-picks did not go well: I had to resolve some nasty conflicts.
- Squashed them into one giant cherry-pick commit
- Pushed it for review

Now, the review has no list of conflicting files. It is not possible to see what the conflicts were and how I resolved them. As the result, the reviewers have to go over this giant change and review everything one more time.

Is this possible to do this nicely? I.e.:

- Merge the set of non consecutive changes to a branch
- See the list of conflicts
- See the diff for conflicts resolve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that there is no way to do it. I had to use an auxiliary branch:

- I found a base merge commit between `master` and `release` by doing `git merge-base master release`.
- Created a branch at this commit.
- Applied all the cherry-picked commit I wanted. Most of them applied nicely with no conflicts.
- Merged this branch back to `master`, resolved conflicts.

This resulted in a merge commit that can be easily reviewed in gerrit. Gerrit allows to diff a patch against both parents (i.e. my branch and `master`) and against the auto-merge. A reviewer can see how conflicts were resolved.